# How to get longest alphabetically ordered substring in python

Tags: python-3.x, alphabetical-sort

I am trying to write a function that returns the longest substring of s in which the letters occur in alphabetical order. For example, if `s = 'azcbobobegghakl'`, the function should return 'beggh'

Here is my function, which is still not complete but it does not return the list of sub; 
the return error is:

> "IndexError: string index out of range"

```
def longest_substring(s):
    sub=[]
    for i in range (len(s)-1):
        subs=s[i]
        counter=i+1
        while ord(s[i])<ord(s[counter]):
            subs+=s[counter] 
            counter+=1
        sub.append(subs)
    return sub
```

Comment: if `counter` exceeds the `len(s)`? in `while` loop and I think your case fails in this input: `acdb` because you are trying to compare all the remaining characters with 1st character `a` so it gives answer as `acdb` which is wrong.. Answer should be `acd` I think..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence

Comment: @cricket_007  that's not right actually ... subsequences can skip elements!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not optimal (works in *linear time* `O(n)`) but i made some modification to your code (in Python 3):

```
def longest_substring(s):
    length = len(s)
    if length == 0 :         # Empty string
        return s
    final = s[0]
    for i in range (length-1):
        current = s[i]
        counter = i+1
        while counter < length and ord(s[i]) <= ord(s[counter]):  
            current += s[counter] 
            counter +=1
            i+=1
        if len(final) < len(current):
            final = current
    return final
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
print(longest_substring(s))
```

Output:

```
beggh
```

> **Modifications:**
>
> - You are comparing character with fixed position i.e. in `while` loop    you are incrementing only `counter` not `i` so I incremented
>     the ith position also.(So we avoid checking the characters which are already checked, So it does this in linear time `O(n)` I think..)
> - Also you are only checking less than for condition `while ord(s[i])<ord(s[counter]):` But you also have to check for equals too.
> - You created one `list` where you append every sequence which is    unnecessary unless you want do any other calculations on the
>     sequence, So I take `string` and if previous sequence's length is small 
>     then I updated it with new sequence.

**Note :** If two sequence's length is same then 1st occurring sequence is shown as output.

Another Input:

```
s = 'acdb'
```

Output:

```
acd
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: what does this part of your code do?: if len(sub) < len(subs):
            sub = subs

Comment: @A.E. if current sequence length is greater than previous  largest sequence then I am assign it to the answer.

Comment: I updated my code , Now it will work in case of empty string and if string length is 1 i.e. `s = 'a'` @A.E.